# Check if a record already exists and update if it exists

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I want to check if a record already exists in a database, and return `true` or `false`.

If it exists, I want to update the `update_at` datetime field.  The method `touch_with_version` from the `paper_trail` gem will do it.

Which is better?

```
  def repeated?(unprocessed)
    occurrence = Occurrence.find_by(unprocessed: unprocessed)
    occurrence.touch_with_version if occurrence.present?
    occurrence.present?
  end
```

Or

```
  def repeated?(unprocessed)
    occurrence = Occurrence.find_by(unprocessed: unprocessed)

    if occurrence.present?
      occurrence.touch_with_version
      true
    else          
      false
    end        
  end
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working within a Rails environment you can use [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try)

```
occurrence.try(:touch_with_version)
occurrence.present?
```

Ruby also provides [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-tap) so you could also write:

```
occurrence.tap({|o| o.try(:touch_with_version)}).present?
```

You could even dig into the libraries to see that `touch_with_version` returns the result of ActiveRecord's `save!` which in turn returns the result of [`create_or_update`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L502) which returns a boolean and so you can write:

```
occurrence.try(:touch_with_version).present?
```

If you're happy returning `true`, `false`, or `nil` you could shorten it to:

```
occurrence.try(:touch_with_version)
```

Very nice but also more fragile if either of those libraries decide to change their return values in a future release.